# How does one access liquid cash with a credit union checking account from a different state when no ATM of the bank is around and checks are rejected?

Tags: credit-card, check, cash, checking-account, credit-unions

My brother recently moved to California and he needs to pay for gas and food for the next 1-3 days.

He has a credit union account and credit card from our local credit union bank.

His credit card recently had a fraudulent charge and was subsequently canceled. The new card is on its way to him.

He has no currency with him, but he has checks for his credit union account. When using the checks at the grocery store, they reject it after entering his new driver's license.

I sent him a Credit Card gift card, but it's delayed, even though I picked expedited 1 day shipping.

Any creative way to quickly convert funds from his credit union account to "liquid cash", or sending him "liquid cash" from any of my accounts (credit card, bank account, crypto, etc.) are appreciated.

What i mean with the expression "liquid cash" is anything that's generally accepted to pay for food and gas, like credit card funds or cash currency.

EDIT: I forgot to specify that **he doesn't have an ATM card**.

Comment: Has he tried cashing a check at a bank? How about ATMs from other banks?

Comment: No, I'll let him know. I didn't know that you could cash checks at banks different from the one you have the account at. Thanks.

Comment: You can also withdraw money using other banks ATM or non-bank ATMs. Presumably he has an ATM card - you only mentioned his credit card getting cancelled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If his credit union participates in the national [Co-Op](https://co-opcreditunions.org/), then he will be able to withdraw money at any participating credit union. He could just bring cash a check out in his name, just like he would at home.

Comment: His credit union is indeed part of the co-op. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If his ATM card is operational and (assuming it is Visa/Mastercard), he can use it at grocery stores and get cashback. Typically, there is no charge for this service.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that he doesn't have an ATM card.